# How to display page from library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, library-project

I have a Base Project which is -Which is `Windows Phone Class Library` which is my library project , in that I have the following:

1) MainPage.xaml
2) AppSetting.cs

```
class AppSettings 
    {
        public virtual string getAppName()
        {
            return "AAA"
        }

        public virtual int getAppVersion()
        {
            return 1
        }
    }
```

I have a Child app which is - `Windows Phone App`

I have referenced the Base Project  how ? right click, Add reference.

I have AppSettings here also :

```
using BaseProject;
class AppSettings : AppSettings
        {
            public override string getAppName()
            {
                return "ABC"
            }

            public override int getAppVersion()
            {
                return 20
            }
        }
```

Now when I run my child app it should display MainPage.xaml from Base Project and also it should take settings from Child app and not from BaseProject.

How to achieve this for Windows Phone 8 app ?

**EDIT 1**

Ok I am able to display MainPage from Base project using the below code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BaseProject;component/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But now how to use methods of child project ? which is in AppSettings.cs

**EDIT 2**

How I am displaying the values ? I have created a object of AppSettings in MainPage.cs in Base Project

```
AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
            string appName = appSettings.getAppName();
            int appVersion = appSettings.getAppVersion();

            App_Name.Text = appName;
            App_Version.Text = "" + appVersion;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use methods from what you describe as your "child" library in the referenced library's code, you need to avoid creating a circular referential dependency. This means that your child library will need to implement an abstract/base class or interface that is defined in your parent library, and instantiate and assign it to a container that the parent library knows about. One way to do this is in your Application class. For instance:

```
namespace BaseProject
{
    public class MyBaseApplication : System.Windows.Application
    {
         // A container the parent library can access
         public BaseProject.AppSettings Settings { get; set; }

         public MyBaseApplication()
         {
             this.Settings = new BaseProject.AppSettings();
         }
    }

    public class MainPage : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var myApp = System.Windows.Application.Current as MyBaseApplication;

            // Will contain an instance of ChildProject.AppSettings
            var mySettings = myApp.Settings;

            string appName = appSettings.getAppName();
            int appVersion = appSettings.getAppVersion();

            App_Name.Text = appName;
            App_Version.Text = "" + appVersion;
        }
    }
}

namespace ChildProject
{
    public class AppSettings : BaseProject.AppSettings
    {
        // Derived implementation
    }

    public class MyChildApplication : BaseProject.MyBaseApplication
    {
        public MyChildApplication() : base()
        {
             // Overwrite the default assignment from the parent class with a new assignment
             this.Settings = new ChildProject.AppSettings();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the System.Windows.Application, which is essentially your Windows Phone app. You can assign it to any memory location your parent library knows about really. This is just one example. You could, for an alternative solution, create a static AppSettingsManager class that has a static settings property you would assign the derived instance to. The only requirement is that the named memory location has to be something the parent library can reference.

Comment: I am bit confused can please explain me, which is child app and which is library project ?

Comment: I guess here CoreLibrary is child app ? if so the problem is I have 2 different apps like this then I cant use CoreLibrary bease my second child app name may be different, I mean the namespace

Comment: You're getting too caught up in the specifics. The only point is that you need some place in your BaseProject library where you can store an instance of AppSettings. BaseProject will create a default instance of AppSettings, and your ChildProject will create a new instance of AppSettings from its own implementation and assign it to that property. I'm making an edit to the code to demonstrate.

Comment: Please wait I will try with you code and let you, can you please wait for me?

Comment: But I have query like how can I dynamically change the name space here ? like this.Settings = new ChildProject.AppSettings(); the name childProject can be anything , I don't want to change anything in my library project

Comment: you can look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290249/how-to-override-the-properties-in-child-project to get better idea

Comment: If you don't understand the effect of reassigning a new instance from a different implementation of the base class, then there's nothing more I can really explain to you. Sorry. If you assign a new instance to the property, the functions of that new instance are called instead of the class instance that was originally there. There's nothing else to it. Read the comments in the sample code above carefully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45829/discussion-between-user2056563-and-lthibodeaux)

Comment: I have few errors like its says "the type or namespace MyBaseApplication does not exist in the namespace" what is the cause ? I already have MyBaseApplication.cs in my BaseProject