# how to override the properties in child project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am working on Windows Phone app Development,

I have 3 projects

1) Library Project

2) Child Project 1 referencing the library project

3) Child Project 2 referencing the library project

In Library project it contains all xaml files,.cs files etc...
In my child project it contain only a MainPage.xaml and its .cs file where I am navigating it to a page in my library project.

But there are few condition in my library project code and it will work based on those conditions like :

In my library project a class can contain:

```
if(language == "JAVA"){
  // alert with text as "Android"
}else{
 // alert with text as "Windows"
}
```

here the string JAVA might be defined in library project like this:

```
public String LanguageName(){
  return "JAVA";
}
```

But in my child project it can be override like:

```
public override String LanguageName(){
      return "C#";
    }
```

So when I execute in should show me a alert with Windows as text , if its not defined in child project then it should alert with default value as Android.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

To `override` a method, the base method must be `virtual`:

```
// in base class
public virtual String LanguageName(){
  return "JAVA";
}


// in derived class
public override String LanguageName(){
  return "C#";
}
```